# <!--hppage status="protected"--> Bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, html, javascript

I've just come across this protection code:

```
<!--hppage status="protected"-->
```

It hides the html and page code from anyone who wants to right click and view source. I can't see a work around to this - so its great...

However is this terrible for SEO?

Comment: Can you give us the URL where you saw this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a comment. You can use view source from your browser menus. However if the rest of the page contains javascript which obscures the page somehow then that won't run when search engines crawl it, so they won't see the content of the page. So yes, bad for SEO.

Comment: That comment is shown when you do view source though so I guess it's hidden by Javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of encryption. Search engines can read levels 1 and 2, but they cannot read level 3. All are hppage status="protected"

Level 1 and 2 are just fine for SEO. The spiders can read them as normal text.

Levels 2 and 3 slow your page load time a bit.